# Wordpress Export CSV

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Задача состоит в экспорте данных желательно в Excel, а именно: все страницы/подстраницы, страницы блогов, и ключевые слова/фразы которые приписаны к этим страницам, используется плагин Rank Math для сео

Comment: WP All Export плагин, не рассматривали?

Comment: Звучит как предложение работы.

Comment: Это либо искать плагин который умеет экспортировать данные в CSV и EXCEL, включая мета поля и тогда тебе понадобиться лишь правильная настройка, либо придётся писать код, который будет занимать 150-500+ строк и требуется анализ и отладка. В таком формате, вряд ли кто поможет. Это тянет на оплату. Посоветую разбить задачу на подзадачи и спрашивать маленькими кусочками, на которые люди легко и быстро ответят. Суть ещё не только в том, что получить описание и ключи, надо ещё и это вывести через например PHPExcel, что потребует строк 60-200, в зависимости от данных.